# Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

Does anyone know how to set a trigger delay of less than 30 seconds (the lowest option given in drop down menu) for Windows task scheduler?  I want a delay of 5 seconds to give another task time to complete first.  Evidently there is no way to daisy chain tasks so that they complete in succession to each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can have them daisy chained. After the first task, schedule the 2nd task to trigger on the event created when the first task completes. The details get a little messy, but it's all explained very well [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davethompson/archive/2011/10/25/running-a-scheduled-task-after-another.aspx).